# matrix norm to given norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider a spd matrix $A$  and define: $$\|y\|_A = \sqrt{y^TAy}$$

Matrix can be written as a cholesky decomposition $A= LL^T$

I want to show that the induced matrix norm is given by: $$\|C\|_A = \|L^T C(L^T)^{-1}\|_2$$

Therefore I compute: 
$$
\sup_{y\ne 0} \frac{\|Cy\|_A}{\|y\|_A}= \sup_{y\ne 0}\frac{\sqrt{(Cy)^T LL^T \cdot Cy}}{\sqrt{y^T LL^Ty}}
$$

How can I go on from there?

Comment: I presume it's $\sqrt{y^TAy}$ and not $\sqrt{y^TAx}$?

Comment: @Gae.S.: Yes sorry

Comment: Is L you take is invertible ? And would you be kind enough to suggest me some reference to study *Cholesky decomposition*?

Comment: @Yes L is invertible. You can  write any spd matrix as the product of a lower triangular matrix L and its conjugate transpose

Comment: Don't you need sup in the last equation?

Comment: @Noobmathematician: Yes I corrected it.

Comment: Do you know how I can go on from there?

Comment: Answered! It have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $L$ invertible
$$
\frac{\|Cy\|_A}{\|y\|_A}
=\frac{\sqrt{(Cy)^T LL^T \cdot Cy}}{\sqrt{y^T LL^Ty}}
=\frac{\sqrt{(L^TCy)^T\cdot (L^T Cy)}}{\sqrt{(L^Ty)^T\cdot L^Ty}}
=\frac{\|(L^T \cdot Cy)\|_2}{\| L^Ty\|_2}
$$
 If  you have $L$ invertible so is $L^T$ is also invertible hence for every $y$  $ \exists! x $ such that  $y = (L^T)^{-1}x$.

Then you have

$$
\sup_{y\ne 0}\frac{\|Cy\|_A}{\|y\|_A}
=\sup_{y \ne 0}\frac{\|(L^T \cdot Cy)\|_2}{\| L^Ty\|_2}
=\sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{\|(L^T \cdot C \cdot  (L^T)^{-1}x   )\|_2}{\| L^T\cdot  (L^T)^{-1}x  \|_2}
=\sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{\|(L^T \cdot C \cdot  (L^T)^{-1}x   )\|_2}{\|x  \|_2}$$$$=\|L^T \cdot C \cdot  (L^T)^{-1}\|_2
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer: In the first line:$\frac{\|(L^T \cdot Cy)\|_2}{\| L^Ty\|_2}$

Comment: Why do you use $|| .||_2$. Don't you need $||. ||_A$?

Comment: Do I need to edit some thing?

Comment: For any vector you know that $\sqrt {x^Tx}= \|x\|_2$

Comment: Am I not correct ?

Comment: I see you can say $L^TCy :=s $ and s is a vector.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:)

Comment: I appreciate your effort:)